# Java : verifying if an object already exists in a List?

Tags: java, list

The probleme is described in details here : https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/3
Shortly to summarize : I successively visit locations thanks to indications given in a text file, and i want to know how many locations I have visited at least once.

I have created a class Point like this :

```
public class Point {
  private int x;
  private int y;

  public Point (int x, int y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
  }

  public int getAbs() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getOrd() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

It is simply a point formed by two coordinates, to indicate the location of a house.
I use it here :

```
public class Exo3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/mpv15_000/Documents/Advent/input3.txt");   
    int c = fr.read();

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    Point init = new Point(x,y);

    List<Point> visitedHouses = new ArrayList<Point>();
    visitedHouses.add(init);

    Boolean b = true;

    while ((c == '^') || (c == 'v') || (c == '<') || (c == '>'))
    {           
      if (c == '^')  
        y++;
      else if (c == 'v')
        y--;    
      else if (c == '<')
        x--;
      else
        x++;

      for (Point p : visitedHouses) {
        if ((p.getAbs() != x) || (p.getOrd() != y))
          b = true;
        else 
          b = false;
      }     

      if (b == true) {
        visitedHouses.add(new Point(x,y));
      }
      c = fr.read();
    }

    System.out.println("Number of houses visited at least once : " + visitedHouses.size());
    fr.close();
  }
}
```

I get "8193", which is the total number of iterations I suppose, but not what I am looking for.
I want to know what are the locations I have visited at least once.
I think the problem comes from the for-loop on the visitedHouses list. 
I would like to compare if the current x and y already exist in a Point located in this list. What should I do ?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but if you want to just track if you've seen something, I'd use a Set instead of a List. Or put the List into a Set for the purposes of checking membership.

Comment: Would a `Set` not solve this problem?  (In addition to an implementation of `hashCode` and `equals`)

Comment: Yes you're right, I made a mistake in copying my code, it's x and y. I edit.

Comment: @MaxZoom Sorted lists have O(log(n)) insertion and lookup times. A `HashSet` has O(1) insertion and lookup times. "The best way" is subjective.

Comment: Either way, implementing `hashCode` and `equals` should be the key here.

Comment: All you need is a `break;`  statement in `false` case at the **visitedHouses** loop.

Comment: @mpv1504 Please accept any answer below by clicking a green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `equals` method in Point class to return true when `x` and `y` are the same. 
something like this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other)
  {
      if (this == other) return true;
      if (!(other instanceof Point)) return false;
      return (this.x == ((Point)other).x) && (this.y == ((Point)other).y);

  }
```

Then use Set instead of List. Set will hold only unique Points.

If you'd like to stay with List just do:

```
    if (b == true)
    {
        Point visitedPoint = new Point(x,y);
        if (!visitedHouses.contains(visitedPoint)) {
           visitedHouses.add(visitedPoint);
        }
    }
```

BTW: how you identify visited House is up to you...

Comment: That inner `if` statement isn't necessary. The `Set` automatically rejects adding an element if it's already contained in the `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

the section of code

```
    for (Point p : visitedHouses)
    {
        if ((p.getAbs() != x) || (p.getOrd() != y))
            b = true;
        else 
            b = false;
    }       

    if (b == true)
    {
        visitedHouses.add(new Point(x,y));
    }
```

looks especially problematic

If you find the "visited" house in the middle of the list, the next entry will not (hopefully) be a duplicate of that house, and will set the "b" flag to false, resulting in a duplicate.

This is due to the programming smell "caching a control variable".  I recommend you don't store control variables (variables that are later checked in if statements to alter the behavior of your block.

```
Point newCandidate = new Point(x,y);
for (Point p : visitedHouses) {
    if (newCandidate.getAbs() == p.getAbs() &&
        newCandidate.getOrd() == p.getOrd()) {
      newCandidate = null;
      break;
    }
}
if (newCandidate != null) {
    visitedHouses.add(newCandidate);
}
```

However, this is still mostly like a control variable.  What would be much faster is if we just used a java `Set` like `HashSet`.

```
public Point {
   ... same stuff you have ...

   @Override
   public int hashcode() {
       return 37*x + 23*y + 13;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object object) {
       if (! object instanceof Point) {
           return false;
       }
       Point other = (Point)object;
       if (this.x != other.x) { return false; }
       if (this.y != other.y) { return false; }
       return true;
   }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Set<Point> visitedHouses = new HashSet<Point>();
// possibly initialize the first house
visitedHouses.add(new Point(0, 0));
while (... visiting each house ...) {
    Point currentHouse = new Point(currentX, currentY);
    visitedHouses.add(currentHouse);
}
```

and rely upon the `Set` interface to assure that you never get a duplicate `Point` entry in the `Collection` as `Set`s cannot contain duplicates (and your `Point` now knows how to take two instances and determine if they are equal).

Not only will the last approach be much faster, since it is stored in a `HashSet` you don't need to go through each `Point` in the `Set` to determine if you have a match for the current location.  The `hashcode(...)` is ran on the "point being used to query the Set" and lookup by it's returned value avoids 99% of the other entries.  The small subset of entries that have a matching hashcode are then compared with the `equals(...)` method to really determine if they are equivalent, or if they "just happen" to have the same hashcode.

Comment: Using `java.util.Objects.hash(x, y)` for the `hashCode` would perhaps be less "magical."

Comment: I'm not sure what you think my comment means. I'm just recommending that you use a built-in hashing algorithm instead of a manual one, in order to avoid having unnecessary magic numbers in the implementation of your `Point#hashCode`.

Comment: @4castle I may have misunderstood what you were referring to as "magical"  If it is the hashing algorithm, then your statement makes more sense (and my prior reply mostly misses the point).  For those who want to "demagic" my algorithm, it's basically an observation that relative primes make a good distribution across a number set.  So, you can take `(some prime) * x + (some other prime) * y + some third prime`  and unless you are incredibly unlucky, you probably have a relative prime distribution, which a non-zero starting point, which makes for a decent hash.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question comment above, you need to break the **visitedHouses** loop, as soon as you find the duplicated point.
For performance, I have changed the condition a bit inside the loop, see below:

```
  boolean found = false;
  for (Point p : visitedHouses) {
    if ((p.getAbs() == x) && (p.getOrd() == y)) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }     

  if (!found) {
    visitedHouses.add(new Point(x,y));
  }
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/IWklR8)